# Comparison sign as variable

Tags: bash

Is it possible to set comparison sign as variable?

I want to do something like that:

```
var1=${1}
var2=${2}
condition=${3}    

if [[ "${var1}" "${condition}" "${var2}" ]]; then
   echo "Warning!"
fi
```

```
./alert.sh "10" "5" ">"
```

Comment: You could replace `[[` with `eval [[`.

Comment: You could also shoot yourself in the foot; neither is probably something you want to do, though. `eval` will evaluate whatever string it gets, rather than just the parts you "expect" to be evaluated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting it is no problem, it's using it that's difficult. (Your code raises a syntax error.)

You could switch from `[[ ]]` to `test`, though [it's not exactly the same](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031).

By the way, `>` is a string operator. You probably wanted `-gt`, the integer operator. See the link above for a table of operators.

```
var1="10"
var2="5"
condition="-gt"

if test "${var1}" "${condition}" "${var2}"; then
   echo "Warning!"
fi
```

Output:

```
Warning!
```

Single square brackets also work ([they're equivalent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/609092/117037)), but for some reason, [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) detects a syntax error, so to make life easier with ShellCheck, I'd say just avoid it, even if that's a bug.

```
[ "${var1}" "${condition}" "${var2}" ]
```

Answer (score -1):

An other way of doing such work is to construct & launch a second script.

It should be easier to debug (you can see & redo directly the cde)

```
echo "
#!/bin/bash
echo "es2 Start"
... write your cdes here ... with parameters you want
```

" > es2

```
chmod +x es2

./es2
```

Comment: Your quoting is wrong, even ignoring the possibility of the variables themselves containing quotes in their values.

Comment: It's just an example you can do what you want ... of course not if you want to copy / paste :-) Hope other people will find the tip useful...

Comment: People needing a tip like this will need to be made aware of the pitfalls of this approach, something you did not address.

Comment: That's precisely why this approach is useful, people can see the real cde (and debug) via the second file ... so I rewrite my answer without "real code"